# Is it possible to run only unit tests with cargo test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust

I have a workspace consisting of both lib and bin crates. Running cargo `test --lib` skips the binary crates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`--bins` and `--lib` are not exclusive, you can use both and it'll run the tests in both categories:

```
$ cargo test --bins
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running target/debug/deps/foo-c982c1477aaaf33d

running 1 test
test test_bins ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

$ cargo test --lib
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running target/debug/deps/foo-532806c187f0c643

running 1 test
test test_lib ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

$ cargo test --bins --lib
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running target/debug/deps/foo-532806c187f0c643

running 1 test
test test_lib ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

     Running target/debug/deps/foo-c982c1477aaaf33d

running 1 test
test test_bins ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

The test project does have an integration test which gets run if no target is provided:

```
$  cargo test
   Compiling foo v0.1.0 (foo)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.27s
     Running target/debug/deps/foo-532806c187f0c643

running 1 test
test test_lib ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

     Running target/debug/deps/foo-c982c1477aaaf33d

running 1 test
test test_bins ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

     Running target/debug/deps/test_foo-79419bfea3135abf

running 1 test
test test_integration ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

   Doc-tests foo

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```